# perl launching external program with environment variables

Tags: perl, parameters

I would like to launch an external command in my perl program under Linux (then capturing the output). But my command has parameters set only by environment variables.
Tried something like that :

```
open CMD, "NSRWATCH=36s;export NSRWATCH;nsrwatch|";
```

but no way.
Any clue ?

Comment: While mob presented better solutions, what you posted *does* work. (`perl -e'open CMD, "NSRWATCH=36s;export NSRWATCH;set|grep ^NSRWATCH= |" or die; print while <CMD>; close CMD;'`)

Comment: "*but no way*" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 2):

Two clues:

Set the environment variable in Perl before calling the external command

```
local $ENV{"NSRWATCH"} = "36s";
open my $CMD, q{-|} , "nsrwatch";
```

or set the variable and run the command in the same statement

```
open CMD, "NSRWATCH=36s nsrwatch |";
```